# PL/SQL function insert into table with pause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a function, which inserts values into a table until I break it.
So I realized the function with a loop. 
But I need to pause the loop after every insert for just one second, because otherwise the database is running out of memory after a short while.

I've tried it with system pause but that's stops the whole instance.

It would be very nice if any one has a idea to resolve this.

Greetings

Comment: If you're running out of memory then you're doing something wrong, but it's impossible to guess what from such a vague description. A hack to pause is only masking the problem. Not that I really understand what you're doing - insert until break doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 4):

> I need to create a function which inserts values into a table until i
>   break it.

If, as you say, you need to interrupt a long running loop at your will, use `dbms_alert` package, and specifically its `register()`, `waitone()` and `signal()` procedures.

Here is an example:

**Session #1**: long running loop.

```
declare
  l_message  varchar2(1000);
  l_astatus  number;
  l_index    number := 0;
  l_maxindex number := 10e3;
begin
  dbms_alert.register('waiting_to_be_broken');
  loop
    l_index := l_index + 1;
    dbms_alert.waitone('waiting_to_be_broken', l_message, l_astatus, 0);
    exit when (l_astatus = 0) or (l_index = l_maxindex);
    insert into t1
       values(l_index);
    dbms_lock.sleep(1);  -- NOTE! We call dbms_lock.sleep(1) here to just  
  end loop;              -- delay(simulation of time consuming operations)       
  if (l_index < 10e3)    -- the loop execution, nothing more.
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('Interrupted!');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Done!');
  end if;
  commit;
end;
/
```

**Session #2**: You've been waiting long enough and decided to interrupt the loop;

```
begin
  dbms_alert.signal('waiting_to_be_broken', '');
  commit;
end;
/
```

**Session #1**: the process is interrupted.

```
Interrupted!                                                                    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Note!** This example is just for the sake of demonstration. Usually execution of DML operations in a loop is not a very good idea. Based on the fact that, as you are saying, you are running out of memory, you need to seriously rethink the way you are approaching the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP (seconds => 1);` after each iteration of your loop.

```
SQL> l
  1  begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'));
  3    DBMS_LOCK.sleep(seconds => 1);
  4    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'));
  5* end;
SQL> /
09:55:42
09:55:43
```

For more information read [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm#ARPLS021)

Comment: and this is only stopping the loop nothing more?

Answer (score 2):

See [DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS021) procedure. For example, I want the execution to stop for 10 seconds :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    START_TM NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    START_TM := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  5    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(10);
  6    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('time taken : ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - START_TM));
  7  END;
  8  /
time taken : 1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, time taken is **1000/100**, i.e. 10 seconds, since the `SLEEP procedure` made a 10 second pause.

**NOTE :**

I just realized your first statement in the question, it says :

> I need to create a function which inserts values into a table

**Why a function for DML?** Is it a pipelined table function or a normal function? If your idea is to hav insert statement inside your normal UDF, then it is bad practice. We can talk about in detail if you wish to.